# Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo: package:// URIs not described

Tags: ros, urdf

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I read through the tutorials [Using A URDF In Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo) and [Using roslaunch files to Spawn Models](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models) I have the impression that it is possible to run Gazebo with ROS without using Gazebo's model database.

To explain, I need to work with some models from ROS using Gazebo. In my view, adding the models to a local database doesn't make sense, because the users of my code just want to git clone and catkin_make and that's all.

So I searched for a way to specify paths to mesh files from my URDF relatively to the package they are contained in. Using the file:// protocol doesn't seem to be a good option, since its resolution is dependent on the working directory.

Somewhere I've found that a package:// protocol can be used, and it actually works in my models. However, there doesn't seem to be any documentation for that. Do you know of docs page that would explain the details and prerequisites for using that?

I've thought about another way to use my models without the need to install them locally. I could just add the package path to GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH. But where to do this? Should I use  tag in the launch file? Do you have any experience with that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6416/using_a_urdf_in_gazebo:-package://-uris-not-described/) by [peci1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/847/peci1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 186 on 2014-06-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you can use the export statement in your `package.xml` to pass this variables to `gazebo_ros`

> ```
>  ...   
> <export>                            
>
>     <gazebo_ros                                                                 
>     gazebo_media_path="${prefix}:/another/path"
> > 
> >         gazebo_plugin_path="${prefix}/lib"    
>
>     gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/../your_models"           
> >         gazebo_resource_path="${prefix}:/path/to/your/resources"/>                    
> </export>
> ...
> ```

This works fine for out projects

This is mentioned in one of the last ros integration tutorials but not really explained...

[ros_plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_plugins)

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/847/peci1/) on 2014-06-24**:
@evilBiber thanks for your tip! Where did you get to know about that? And how does it work? The plugin tag only references the shared library file, which IMO doesn't have any link to the package.xml of its original package. Or does it?

**Comment by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on 2015-03-13**:
What is the value of ${prefix} here? @evilBiber

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2015-06-10**:
${prefix} is always the path of the package.xml itself/

**Comment by [Lyndwyrm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2869/lyndwyrm/) on 2016-10-18**:
This doesn't work for me, because I still have to manually set the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH in my bash file.
Do I have to add something special to the CMake file?

**Comment by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3790/oscar-lima/) on 2017-09-06**:
check that your package.xml file has: <run_depend>gazebo_ros</run_depend>

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/559/airuno2l/) on 2018-02-09**:
Now it's <exec_depend> instead of <run_depend>

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/559/airuno2l/) on 2018-02-09**:
exec_depend instead of run_depend now